# Typescript stripe cloud functions with firebase

Tags: javascript, typescript, stripe-payments

I am writing cloud functions in typescript and when I am attempting to use the cloud function, stripe is giving me an issue. I have the compiler option `allowJs` set to true because I thought that was necessary. Do I have to initialize stripe multiple times throughout the project at the top of each file? Here is what I had and an error was thrown saying "stripe is undefined at line 91"

```
export class Invoice {

    stripe: any
    customer: Customer;

    constructor(stripe: any) {
        this.customer = new Customer();
        this.stripe = stripe;
    }

    somethingToDoWithStripe() {
        this.stripe.doSomething();
    }
}
```

stripe would then be undefined which I do not understand. I am fairly new to typescript, so an example of how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Invoice use example:

```
let invoice = new Invoice(stripe);
invoice.somethingToDoWithStripe();
```

Comment: It is passed to the constructor. @aristotll

Comment: How do you use `Invoice`, please provide more code examples.

Comment: @aristotll done

Comment: The code is ok, are you sure `stripe` is defined?

Comment: Yea... It is like var stripe = require('stripe')(token)

Comment: @aristotll What do you think I should do?

Comment: Can you try including stripe at the top of the file?

Comment: I included it, so I'm not sure what the issue is..